# Reducing the water pressure reduction?

Tags: water-pressure

My house has a pressure reducing valve. [image: valve] I wish I had a bit more water pressure. Can I adjust this thing?

Comment: Do you have a pressure gauge you can hook up to a hose connection? If not, get one and come back to us here...

Comment: Also, can you take a sharper photo and post it? Your existing one is hideously blurry and I can't read the label on your valve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can. The picture is indeed very blurry. You'll need a biggish screwdriver, and a wrench. You hold the screw steady with the screwdriver while loosening the nut, then turn the screwdriver a bit (don't go crazy) and then hold it and retighten the nut. Having a gauge installed and checking the pressure when nothing is drawing water, but also when things are will give some insight as to how well it's working (sometimes "low perceived pressure" and "PRV not working as it should" are related.)

Comment: Picture improved.

Comment: That regulator looks to old enough to need replacing.

Comment: I do not concur - it's nowhere near ancient, and in any case, function is a far better indicator than external appearance. Here's the instructions, @bmargulies  http://media.wattswater.com/1915088.pdf  - I note that there is a strainer which can be cleaned, as well as the expected adjustment procedure. It's also rebuildable.